# Apply ButtonStyle Properties to All Buttons Globally

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I've implemented several long ListViews containing ElevatedButtons in my flutter project, and would now like to apply various ButtonStyle properties to all of them. I am certain there is a way to avoid applying these properties to each button individually, but haven't been able to find anything in the Flutter docs or on Stack Overflow. Can this task be done globally?

Currently buttons have basic styling:

```
            ElevatedButton(
                style: const ButtonStyle(),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => authorA()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Author A")),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: const ButtonStyle(),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthorB()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Author B")),
            ElevatedButton(
                style: const ButtonStyle(),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthorC()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Author C)")),
```

My ListView contains hundreds of these buttons, and there are several other long ListViews containing buttons that I would like to style as well. what if I wanted to modify the ButtonStyle() property for all of them like below:

```
            ElevatedButton(
                style:   ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthorA()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Author A")),
```

Comment: i don't understand completely, can you please send the code

Comment: Added, thanks for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `theme` or `darkTheme` property of `MaterialApp` to set global styles.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**main.dart**

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.orange,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> A ButtonStyle that overrides the default appearance of
> ElevatedButtons when it's used with **ElevatedButtonTheme** or with the
> overall Theme's ThemeData.elevatedButtonTheme.
>
> The style's properties override ElevatedButton's default style, i.e.
> the ButtonStyle returned by ElevatedButton.defaultStyleOf. Only the
> style's non-null property values or resolved non-null
> MaterialStateProperty values are used.

```
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same properties add different styles as you want this is possible using .. Operator.

```
ElevatedButton(
                style: const ButtonStyle()..,//Just Add .. here and add new color and properties
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => authorA()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Author A")),
```

Answer (score 0):

use -> MaterialApp -> theme -> elevatedButtonTheme -> style -> with styleForm -> primary : #Color

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).